# How to prevent click outside React Modal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently using [react-modal](https://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/) package.

I want to disable click and scroll outside react modal component.

Comment: You have to show what progress you've done so far. Show us your code and explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 20):

add this line to your modal component

```
    <ReactModal 
       //other props declaration..
       shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false} // add this to prevent outside click to prevent modal close 
    >
```

or use `event.preventDefault()` to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Add backdrop= "static"

```
 <Modal
        dialogClassName="popup-box"
        show={showPopup}
        backdrop="static" // Add this line to prevent closing on click outside
        size="lg"
        scrollable="true"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Add a class to the parent element when the modal opens,

```
.inactive {
  pointer-events: none; // pointer-events not supported below IE11
  position: fixed;
}
```

If your have wrapped the entire page in the modal Wrapper, then add this class to the wrapper

Comment: if it's a parent element this won't allow closing or interacting with modal either

Answer (score 0):

use `shouldCloseOnOverlayClick` prop for `<ReactModal />` for outside click. when the modal is open, it adds `.ReactModal__Body--open` to body. (it's rename-able.) You can add `overflow-y: auto;` to that class in css for outside scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the toggle attribute to the modal . tag

```
<Modal toggle={()=>this.handlename()}></Modal>
```